# making the Google Chrome Developer Tools semi-transparent

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I find the Chrome Developer Tools somewhat obstructive because I cannot see what is behind. Is it possible to make them semi-transparent? I have tried

`opacity: 0.5`

but that doesn't show the content that is behind, simply makes the console less readable.

Comment: I undock the whole thing completely, because it affects the layout of the page otherwise.

Comment: @Esailija: Even with undocking, I can't make the page semi-transparent.